# How can I have an custom simulation speed adjuster in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model in Anylogic, where I need to create a custom simulation speed adjuster.

How can I have a custom simulation speed adjuster like the image below,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button with code such as below:
[image]

the first line ensures you are not in the "max speed" mode, the second lets you choose whatever speed scale you like.

And the help has all other API calls to help you further: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/running/controlling-model-execution.html#controlling-the-model-execution-from-code